# mongodb: check condition in aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am using mongodb 3.6. I have many document in my collection.inside the document i do not have any **Domain** field. I create **Domain** for some document.
Now I want to use aggregate for filtering this collection. that is mean, I want those documents that have not **Domain** as a field.

```
db.Events.aggregate([
    {$project : {
        Domain : {$filter: {
            input: "$Domain",
            cond:{if: {Domain : {$exists: false}}, then: {"$BusinessCode": 1} }}}
    }
        }
],{
allowDiskUse: true
})
```

when I execute this script I got error:

```
Assert: command failed: {
"ok" : 0,
"errmsg" : "Unrecognized expression '$exists'",
"code" : 168,
"codeName" : "InvalidPipelineOperator"
} : aggregate failed
```

seems `$exists` is not supported into `$filter expression`.
How could I do that?

Another question is: Can I use 2 $project like this:

```
db.Events.aggregate([
    {$project : {
        Domain : {$filter: {
            input: "$Domain",
            cond:{if: {Domain : {$exists: false}}, then: {"$BusinessCode": 1} }}}
    }
        },
    {
        $match : {BusinessCode: /(([1-2]?[0-9])-([0-9]*)-([0-9]*)-([0-9]*)-([0-9]*)-([0-9]*)-([0-9]*))/}
    },
    {
        $project : {BusinessCode : {$arrayElemAt:[{$split : ["$BusinessCode", "-"]},0]}}
    },
    {
        $addFields: {"Domain":  "$BusinessCode"}
    },
],{
    allowDiskUse: true
  })
```

I want to check, does specific field is there into document. if does not exist, BusinessCode  projected and other stuff..

***************************Edit****************

this is my sample of documents:

```
"DeviceId" : "xxxxxxx",
"UserId" : UUID(""),
"UserFullName" : "test-user",
"SystemId" : "com.messaging",
"SystemTitle" : "message",
"EventId" : "messaging.message",
"EventTitle" : "test",
"EventData" : [],
"BusinessCode" : "1-2-4-4-5-6-9",...
```

After execute this script, I expect "Domain" append to my document like this:

```
"EventTitle" : "test",
"EventData" : [],
"BusinessCode" : "1-2-4-4-5-6-9"
"Domain": "1" // 1 is first number of BusinessCode that splitted
```

but if **Domain** was exist script goes to next document and check again.

Comment: Could you add some sample documents and expected result of your $project ?

Comment: @mickl I have updated my post

Comment: Thanks, I need one more clarification: is Domain an array inside of Event (which you want to reshape) or is it a single field that sometimes exists and sometimes not ?

Comment: @mickl Domain is a single and independent field that should  just save the first string of BusinessCode. If exist script for increase the response must deny it add "Doamin" filed to other documents that have not this field.

Comment: Thanks, I've asked because you're using $filter which is dedicated for nested arrays

Comment: yes, I got but I do not know which expression I have to use!! this is my problem :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you're looking for a something like COALESCE in SQL and it is called [`$ifNull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) in MongoDB. For instance:

```
db.Events.save({Domain: "4"})
db.Events.save({BusinessCode: "1-2-4-4-5-6-9"})

db.Events.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            Domain: { 
                $ifNull: [ "$Domain", { $arrayElemAt: [ { $split : ["$BusinessCode", "-"] },0] } ] }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: What is happen when Domain exist?

Comment: Then it is projected into final result

Comment: COALESCE or NVL?

Comment: @Saravana I have background in T-SQL, NVL works similarly in Oracle :)

Comment: @mickl oh ok, in Oracle COALESCE and NVL are to achieve the same thing, NVL accepts only 2 args, COALESCE accepts multiple args, the first non null will be returned